# How could two identical HDDs with identical content have different amount of free space?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, sync

I have HDD1 and HDD2. I use the second one as the backup of the first one.
Both of them are the same brand and type (Toshiba 3,5" 2TB HDD 7200rpm), I purchased them together. I use Windows 10 Pro x64 with latest updates and drivers.

I use FreeFileSync for backing up (syncing) my data to the second drive. I synced everything today twice and FreeFileSync tells me everything was synced successfully. No difference between the drives.

**However the first one has 400GB free space on it and the backup drive has 500GB free space!

- I emptied all Recycle Bins

- I re-synced with FreeFileSync (still tells me there's no difference)

- Checked even the contents of both drives (SHA-1 check with Total Commander). It also tells me everything is the same on them.

- Scanned both of them with Windows CHKDSK. No error on any of them.

- I defragment both of them regularly (last time today). Zero fragmented files on both of them.**

Any ideas? 
How have I lost 100 GB of free disk space on my first drive?

Comment: I think windows maybe taken 100Gb of the first drive for recovery and such. It's hidden outside the normal partition and so you don't see the space there.
Check the 'total' capacity of each drive via the properties, I bet the smaller one has a smaller total capacity too.

Comment: Checked with Windows Disk Management. Both of them has only 1 partition on them with a total capacity of 1865,02 GB. It's identical.  :-(

Comment: Ok that's strange, how about swap space? 100Gb is slightly overkill but it's possible I guess?

Comment: How do you mean? What swap space?

Comment: You mean pagefile? System restore is off because I use a better backup software and pagefile is also turned off in my Windows, since my OS is installled on SSD.

Comment: Yeah page file, ok last thing I can think of is shadow copies of files, but I'm unsure if they use space or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's no solution for this problem.

I re-formatted the entire HDD1 (with the false free space), then copied back everything (took me about 6 hours) from the backup drive HDD2. Now both drives have the same amount of free space, so HDD1 never had any physical problems, it was some kind of Windows error.

If anyone has an idea what caused this and how to prevent problems like this in the future please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your recycle bin was corrupted.
I had a similar problem between 2 disks, same number of files, occupying the same amount of space... but 40BG lost between 2 identical disks.

```
rd /s /q F:\$Recycle.bin
```

solved my issue. [rd documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rd)

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/recycle-bin-is-corrupted-windows

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes to my mind is to try utility like https://windirstat.net/ to see what is using your disk space. Hopefully you'll find large 100GB space that doesn't look like your file(s).

Comment: I checked with TreeSize Professional, which is even better than Windirstar, but I don't see any difference between the drives.  :-(

Comment: Maybe it doesn't display system files or some protected area.
Try a http://www.piriform.com/defraggler than, it has portable version (no need to install) and can show all disk contents after Analyze (without need to defragment)

Comment: Did it but didn't help. Analyzed with Defraggler. It found 16 fragmented files. I defragmented them. Now it shows that disk health is good. But it shows the same amount of free space as Windows does. It's still lacks 100 GB compared to he other.