# Drive Overview gives diffrent Disk Usage than properties

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I am on the Startpage of Explorer and press Properties of the Drive, i get the following details:

[image]

But if I open the drive, select all folders and files in there (Show Hidden turned on) it only shows 1,29 TB instead of 2,63TB. So I am confused what files I am missing? Are there some even deeper hidden files than "Hidden Files"?

[image]

Comment: System Volume Information and the Recycle Bin file may not be counted in the Properties. To put it simply, your second image contains the properties only of the files and folders you have permission to view attributes of.

Comment: The trash is 12GB. I don't think that System Volume Information is 1TB. If I only copy the to me visible part, will this be enough or may important data be lost?

Comment: It depends. The drive is called Backup. How are you backing up to it? Is it a program that performs the backups, or do you just copy data to it? If you're just copying data to it, copying data from it will capture all necessary data. If you're using an application to perform these backups you will need to research the specifics of the methods of backup and how to move those backups to a different storage location.

Comment: There are actually quite a few similar questions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1118614/windows-10-reporting-wrong-hard-disk-free-space https://superuser.com/questions/1174777/how-could-two-identical-hdds-with-identical-content-have-different-amount-of-fre https://superuser.com/questions/917110/why-does-windirstat-report-less-space-used-than-windows-does https://superuser.com/questions/304474/why-dont-the-sizes-of-my-folders-add-up-to-the-size-of-my-hard-drive-in-windows

Comment: @music2myear It was my first BackUp Drive. It ist just drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

Because the data has just been placed by drag-and-drop (copy/paste), you can safely move all of the data off by doing the same.

There are many reasons why there is a difference between the various measurements of disk usage, the questions linked above deal with those.

But, if your actual question is whether you can simply copy/paste the content off of the drive and be certain you are getting all of it, and as you noted all of the data on the drive got there by copy/paste, then the answer is "yes, copy/paste will get all of the necessary data off the drive to elsewhere."